# power shell script to get data from each subfolders

Tags: powershell

[image]I have a folder inside this folder I have around 20 sub folders, each sub folder having .wav files and I have a power shell script using this script I am able to get data from a single folder, but I want to get data from all sub folders in one go when I click on main folder. Below is my power shell script. Please help me to modify my script.

```
# Show an Open Folder Dialog and return the directory selected by the user.
function Read-FolderBrowserDialog([string]$Message, [string]$InitialDirectory, [switch]$NoNewFolderButton)
{
    $browseForFolderOptions = 0
    if ($NoNewFolderButton) { $browseForFolderOptions += 512 }

    $app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, $Message, $browseForFolderOptions, $InitialDirectory)
    if ($folder) { $selectedDirectory = $folder.Self.Path } else { $selectedDirectory = '' }
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app) > $null
    return $selectedDirectory
}
$folder= Read-FolderBrowserDialog
$com = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($folder)
for($i = 0; $i -lt 64; $i++) {
                $name = $com.GetDetailsOf($com.Items, $i)
                if ($name -eq 'Length') { $lengthattribute = $i}
}
$com.Items() |
ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
Name = $_.Name
Path = $_.Path
Size = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 1)
DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 4)
Length = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, $lengthattribute)
}
} |
Export-csv report.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Please read the help about asking [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite a PowerShell way anymore to use Com-objects for folder operations and I generally don't like mixing UI controls with scripts, unless those are controllers.

Once you know the `$folder` as the parent, I would filter sub-directories and then foreach subdir I would recursively measure the files within, enrich the original object and select the relevant Properties. Something like:

```
$folder | Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $files = ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length);
    $_ |
    Add-Member -NotePropertyName FileCount -NotePropertyValue $files.Count -PassThru |
    Add-Member -NotePropertyName Length -NotePropertyValue $files.Sum -PassThru
} |
Select Name,FileCount,Length,LastWriteTime
```

So you will get a result like:

```
Name           FileCount   Length LastWriteTime
----           ---------   ------ -------------
subfolder_A          499   679695 2/02/2017 12:23:21 PM
subfolder_B           35    21033 12/01/2017 1:36:53 PM
subfolder_C           18    10777 12/01/2017 1:38:28 PM
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered. But still if you want to try by your approach, then you can use the `Type` method of `$com.Items()` Marshal object. One way will be to check if an item is of `type` `File Folder`. If yes, then you can use `-Recurse` parameter along with `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to list all subfolders and files in your folders. Your code will look something like this

```
# Show an Open Folder Dialog and return the directory selected by the user.
function Read-FolderBrowserDialog([string]$Message, [string]$InitialDirectory, [switch]$NoNewFolderButton)
{
    $browseForFolderOptions = 0
    if ($NoNewFolderButton) { $browseForFolderOptions += 512 }

    $app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, $Message, $browseForFolderOptions, $InitialDirectory)
    if ($folder) { $selectedDirectory = $folder.Self.Path } else { $selectedDirectory = '' }
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app) > $null
    return $selectedDirectory
}
$folder= Read-FolderBrowserDialog
$com = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($folder)
for($i = 0; $i -lt 64; $i++) {
                $name = $com.GetDetailsOf($com.Items, $i)
                if ($name -eq 'Length') { $lengthattribute = $i}
}
$com.Items() | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Type -ne "File Folder")
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Size = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 1)
        DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 4)
        Length = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, $lengthattribute)}
    } 
} | Export-csv report.csv  -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation

$com.Items() | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.Type -eq "File Folder")
    {
        Get-ChildItem -path $Folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Size = $_.Length/1KB
        DateCreated = $_.CreationTime }
        }
    }
}  | Export-csv report.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
```

I have used `-append` and `-force` parameters to output everything in one `CSV`.
The above script will list you files in subfolders of a folder as well as in the subfolders of subfolders. Also, it will list out the folders in you root directory. I think this is what you were looking for. You can anyway add more conditions depending upon your requirement, that's why instead of continuing in a single `Foreach-Object`, I have split the `Foreach-Object` into the number of conditions (2 in this case, one for folders and another for files within subfolders). You can tweak around this script depending upon your requirements.

Comment: Hi Vivek thanks for the reply,Actually my script only able to get data from single folder but i want to get data from multiple folders in one go example:- i have a folder name Audio files inside this folder i have Pankaj folder having two .wav files and Rajesh folder having two .wav files and Vaibhav folder having two .wav files. when i click on Audio files folder after clicking loop through each sub folders, and get detail like Name,Path,Size,DateCreated,Length of each .wav files to csv.the require output is showing in picture.

Answer (score -1):

Actually this whole thing could be done way easier if you just take the childitem of a path and then check for the childitem of that path. So just do this and enjoy the bright side of life.

```
$folder = Get-Childitem 'C:\'

Get-Childitem $folder
```

If you want to work with the Output just put Get-Childitem $folder into another variable, like this.

```
$folder2 = Get-Childitem $folder
```

I hope i was able to help you out on this buddy ;).